# Alternative for Tags in flutter

Tags: flutter, tags

This is the older version of an application. I used Tags widget in that app. But now Tags doesn't support null safety and outdated. Can you please suggest me alternative and write same functional code using alternate packages.

```
import 'package:flutter_tags/flutter_tags.dart';


List<Items> _newArrivalsItems = [];
  List<Items> _selectedNewArrivalsItems = [];
  List<String> _selectedNewArrivalsItemCodes = [];


Widget _buildFilter() {
    List<String> added = [];

    return Container(
      child: Tags(
        runSpacing: 5,
        spacing: 5,
        itemCount: _newArrivalsItems.length,
        itemBuilder: (index) {
          final obj = _newArrivalsItems[index];
          if (added.contains(obj.iGRPCODE)) {
            return Container();
          }
          added.add(obj.iGRPCODE);
          return ItemTags(
            index: index,
            title: obj.iGRPDESC,

            active: true,
            removeButton: ItemTagsRemoveButton(
              onRemoved: () {
                // Remove the item from the data source.
                setState(() {
                  // required
                  _selectedNewArrivalsItemCodes.remove(obj.iGRPCODE);
                  setState(() {});
                });
                //required
                return true;
              },
            ), // OR null,
            onPressed: (item) {
              final value = _selectedNewArrivalsItemCodes.remove(obj.iGRPCODE);
              if (!value) _selectedNewArrivalsItemCodes.add(obj.iGRPCODE);
              setState(() {});
            },
            onLongPressed: (item) => print(item),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 'flutter_tags_x' as alternative and it is working fine.
Thanks for the responses

Answer (score 0):

There is a prerelease version with null safety

```
dependencies:
  flutter_tags: "^1.0.0-nullsafety.1"
```

If you are not interested in that, you can create custom tags by yourself using the Chip widget

[More here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Chip-class.html)